# Retrieve child img src (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple div's that look like this:

```
<div><a href="our_work.html?clientid=39">
<img src="filestore/data_logos/39.gif" alt="client logo"/>
</a></div>
```

I am trying to get the image src if you click on the div layer:

```
$('#carousel div').click(function(event) {
  alert($(this).children('img').attr('src'));
});
```

The alert always comes back as null, any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#carousel div').click(function(event) {
  alert($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

The images aren't children of the div...they're children of the `<a>` which is a child of the div, need to go one more level down.

Comment: +1 - `.children()` will return only **direct descendants** where `.find()` will search through all elements underneath; children, grandchildren, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('#carousel div').click(function(event) {
  alert($('img', this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[Straight from the horse's mouth](http://api.jquery.com/children/), emphasis mine:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .children() method allows us to search through the **immediate** children of these elements in the DOM tree...

The IMG is nested like this: `DIV > A > IMG`; what you need is `find()` not `children()`.